# Do we really need the copyright tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I've looked at the list of questions which have this tag(331 at the moment) and from my point of view this tag should be removed(or maybe even blacklisted). A decent number of those questions are already closed as offtopic and the vast majority which are still open should be closed(as being offtopic) as they generally ask for legal advice. Just a few examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891253/is-it-ok-if-my-ios-app-has-the-same-name-as-an-existing-trademark

[Why is the year 2001 missing from GNU make copyright?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538496/why-is-the-year-2001-missing-from-gnu-make-copyright)

[Do copyright dates need to be updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390230/do-copyright-dates-need-to-be-updated)

[How can I change the copyright template in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770126/how-can-i-change-the-copyright-template-in-xcode-4) (like another small number of questions tagged with [copyright](/questions/tagged/copyright), the tag isn't really necessary)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094103/is-copying-an-api-a-breach-of-copyright

[I am releasing a PHP application for a friend to use, should I copyright it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653092/i-am-releasing-a-php-application-for-a-friend-to-use-should-i-copyright-it)

Blacklisting this tag might(well, I don't know if this will really happen) even discourage future users on asking offtopic questions related to copyright issues on stackoverflow.

Comment: FYI, out of 331 questions [76 are closed](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+%5Bcopyright%5D). I dont think it is a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for Stack Overflow but it may be off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it makes sense to actually *blacklist* the tag.  A copyright is an actual thing, so I'm not sure that I have an issue with it, as long as there's something that's on topic for Stack Overflow.

The tag wiki for [copyright](/questions/tagged/copyright) states:

> The copyright tag is for issues relating to the creation and/or display of copyright information.

I am ok with the tag being used for *this* purpose, but I think the tag should be renamed [copyright-display](/questions/tagged/copyright-display).

That said, here's what I think should happen:

For each question that the [copyright](/questions/tagged/copyright) tag is on:

- Review the question for quality.  Vote to close, or flag for moderator attention as appropriate to seal the deal
- If the tag on the question is not for the purposes of the display of copyright, then remove it.  If it is, add the new tag.

The important thing here is to place the emphasis on getting rid of the bad questions, not on removing the tag.

The tag won't be blacklisted; 331 questions is nothing compared to say the [books](/questions/tagged/books) or [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) question, which is a consistent problem.

Comment: I already started to review the questions. Regarding the use of the tag on stackoverflow, here is a comment(from one of the users that asked such a question) in response to another user who told him the question was offtopic: *I thought that the copyright tag was made for such issue* . This was the reason for my proposal.